# sqlalchemy error 2013 Lost connection during query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

python 3.11
sqlalchemy 1.4.22
mysql 8.0.35
sshtunnel 0.4.0

I am querying a database on a remote server in the context of a Fast API.

Here is how I create the connection engine, in my sessions.py file:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
(ssh_host, ssh_port),
   ssh_username=ssh_user,
   ssh_password=ssh_pwd,
   remote_bind_address=(mysql_host, mysql_port)
) as tunnel:
    port = str(tunnel.local_bind_port)
    # SQLAlchemy connection string
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"mysql+mysqldb://{mysql_username}:{mysql_password}@127.0.0.1:{port}/rso"
    engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_recycle=1800)
    SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
    try:
        with engine.connect() as connection:
            result = connection.execute(text("SELECT 1"))
        print("Database connection successful!")
    except Exception as e:
       print(f"Database connection failed! ERROR: {e}")
```

The print("Database connection successful!") is printed allright.

I then try to query the DB using the following:

```
from typing import Any, Dict, Generic, List, Optional, Type, TypeVar, Union

from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from app.db.base_class import Base

ModelType = TypeVar("ModelType", bound=Base)
CreateSchemaType = TypeVar("CreateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
UpdateSchemaType = TypeVar("UpdateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)


class CRUDBase(Generic[ModelType]):
    def __init__(self, model: Type[ModelType]):
        """
        CRUD object with default methods to Create, Read, Update, Delete (CRUD).
        **Parameters**
        * `model`: A SQLAlchemy model class
        * `schema`: A Pydantic model (schema) class
        """
        self.model = model

    def get(self, db: Session, id: Any) -> Optional[ModelType]:
        return db.query(self.model).filter(self.model.id == id).first()
```

I get the following error the first time I try to query the DB:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

If I don't reboot the uvicorn server, the next time I try to query the DB using the same CRUDBase.get method, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:33163' (111)")
```

I have tried the methods explained [here](https://sebhastian.com/lost-connection-mysql-server-during-query/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755228/sqlalchemy-mysql-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query), eg increasing the connect_timeout value to 600, with no success.

Any idea on why this is happening ?

Thanks.